# How to enable dm-crypt on Ceph OSD with cephadm?

Tags: ceph, dmcrypt

I had originally used the following website (https://computingforgeeks.com/install-ceph-storage-cluster-on-ubuntu-linux-servers/) to stand up a Ceph cluster on Ubuntu 22.04 with Cephadm and Ansible. One of the steps shows how to configure the OSDs, but I was wondering if there is a way to do a similar step but with dm-crypt enabled?

```
# ceph orch daemon add osd ceph-osd-01:/dev/sdb
# ceph orch daemon add osd ceph-osd-02:/dev/sdb
# ceph orch daemon add osd ceph-osd-03:/dev/sdb
```

Is there a simplified how-to document or cheat sheet on how to enable dm-crypt on Ceph OSDs?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to deploy multiple OSDs at once is a spec file:

```
service_type: osd
service_id: example_osd_spec
placement:
  host_pattern: '*'
spec:
  data_devices:
    all: true
  encrypted: true
```

The "encrypted: true" option would create encrypted OSDs. You can't encrypt existing OSDs, you would need to redeploy them.
Check out the [docs](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephadm/services/osd/#additional-options) for more information.

Comment: How does one apply a spec file to ceph? I used cephadm and ansible to deploy the initial cluster configuration.

Comment: It's on the page I linked:
`ceph orch apply -i spec.yml`